# JS split for Japanese string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, validation, split

I have a form with string validation. The validation the string must contain at least two words. I am using the `split()` method

```
string.split(' ').length >= 2
```

However, if user input Japanese string ex:

> 公開文書

The result of `公開文書.split(' ').length` is `1`, and the value is not valid for my form. But, if I translate the string from Japanese to English we get the translation: `Public document`, and it looks like a valid string for the form.

Is there a way to handle such a case? I want to make such Japanese strings valid.

Comment: Either allow all Japanese (probably not acceptable) or translate before doing the split.  If you need it in English then you need it in English - that's your answer right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you are asking to split a string by a space. Japanese text inherently does not contain spaces. The system doesn't care whether, *when translated*, it would contain a space.

With Japanese, we are really more concerned with whether there are multiple words. If you are addressing Japanese specifically, I would suggest [tiny-segmenter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-segmenter). For example:

```
var segmenter = new TinySegmenter()
var segs = segmenter.segment("公開文書") // Output [ '公開', '文書' ]
var num_words = segs.length >= 2 // true
```

Do note that this is only for Japanese text. You will need to find a similar solution for other languages, such as Chinese or Korean.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you need it for chinese

https://github.com/bluelovers/node-segment

```
var Segment = require('novel-segment');
var segment = new Segment();

var ret = segment.doSegment('公開文書');

console.log(ret.length); // => 2
console.log(ret);
```

---

```
{
    "w": "公開",
    "p": 4096,
    "f": 1254,
    "ps": "動詞 動語素",
    "pp": "0x1000",
    "_debug": {
        "index": 0,
        "ps_en": "v"
    }
},
{
    "w": "文書",
    "p": 1048576,
    "f": 6704,
    "ps": "名詞 名語素",
    "pp": "0x100000",
    "_debug": {
        "index": 1,
        "ps_en": "n"
    }
}
```

Comment: @chade_ ok i fixed it now, somehow stackoverflow always block me if i post code > other desc

Comment: Thanks for editing it, It looks much better now. I retracted my NAA flag. For the downvote, I can't say more than that it doesn't come from me. I'd suggest to add some explanation into your post (if possible), which normally can help to more likely get an upvote. :D

Comment: @chade_ thx for u tell me fix too, just some time i can't post code because stackoverflow tell me write more desc lol, but i can't

Comment: I'm puzzled why are you not able to write a description. Code explanations are always encouraged, and I have not run into a case where I was unable to do so. Code *without* a description, though, does occur. Is there a common situation where SO allows code, but not  descriptions to be entered ?

Comment: @SherylHohman my all human lang ( include english ) is super bad, so sometime i only can hope other ppl can see what i mean lol

Comment: np. always worth trying best you can, then getting editing help from friends or fellow SO members. As stated earlier, SO frowns on posted code without a problem description. All the best, and thanks for sharing. Looks super useful.